# Create date histogram chart with google histogram

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, histogram

How to create Google Histogram Chart [1] that works with dates?

I've placed sample code (with working number and non-working date examples): http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/417/ and code below [2]

[1] https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram

[2]

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function str_to_utcdate(d) {
    return new Date(d.substr(0, 4), d.substr(5, 2) - 1, d.substr(9, 2));
}

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['item', 'date'],
        ['a', str_to_utcdate('2001-07-01')],
        ['b', str_to_utcdate('2001-07-01')],
        ['c', str_to_utcdate('2001-07-01')], ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart.draw(data);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['item', 'date'],
        ['a', 10],
        ['b', 20],
        ['c', 30], ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart.draw(data);

}
```

Comment: Dates are not yet supported for Histograms.  You can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support.

Comment: Added feature request https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1457. Any way to emulate support? Could convert date to number, but how to fix up labels and axis?

Comment: You can fix the labels by setting the formatted values of the date column, but there is no way to adjust the axis labels in Histogram charts.

Comment: Nearly 2 years later, dates are still not supported for Histograms http://jsfiddle.net/paul_h/Qquse/1569/

Comment: Just to add another comment... after 4 years+, dates are still not supported for histograms ^_^

Comment: many years later...

Comment: @RhoPhi was it added?

Answer (score 1):

5 years now and Histograms still don't support dates. Since I ain't got time and I need my stuff done, I made a workaround (so ugly it hurts) but works.

First, I defined a format just to put a keyword at the start of each label. In my case, since I have only one chart in my page, I just used the keyword 'date'.

```
const keyword = 'date';
const options = {
      // ...
      hAxis: {
        format: `'${keyword}'#`
      },
}
```

If you have multiple charts in your page and you want them to behave differently, you might want to define different keyword to each one.

Now, using query selector, I selected all the label elements that are of my interest

```
let labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#chart svg g:nth-of-type(3) g:nth-of-type(3) g text'));
```

In my case, my chart was set in a DIV with id 'chart'. If you're using any other id, just replace `#chart` with your id;

Then I will filter only the labels which start with my keyword 'date'

```
labels = labels.filter(g => g.innerHTML.startsWith(keyword));
```

With that, I replace the `innerHTML` of each element to the date format I wish.

```
labels.forEach(g => {

    const date = new Date(+g.substring(keyword.length));
    // you can apply any format method you wish

    // .toLocaleDateString()
    g.innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString();

    // moment.js
    g.innerHTML = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM');

});
```

Also, I'm using interactive charts, so the labels refresh on each user interaction. Therefore, I put everything inside an interval, and the final result is as follows:

```
const keyword = 'date';
const options = {
      // ...
      hAxis: {
        format: `'${keyword}'#`
      },
}

// ... chart setup

setInterval(() => {
    let labels = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#chart svg g:nth-of-type(3) g:nth-of-type(3) g text'));
    labels = labels.filter(g => g.innerHTML.startsWith(keyword));
    labels.forEach(g => {
        const date = new Date(+g.substring(keyword.length));
        g.innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString();
    });
}, 100);
```

**Use this answer with caution.** Using query selectors to modify third party generated content is very unsafe because it relies on the hope that the third-party developers won't modify the way the content is generated.

Answer (score -1):

Try out this column chart:

```
public histogramChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    dataTable: [
        ['Date', 'Number'],
        [new Date(2015, 1, 1), 5],
        [new Date(2015, 1, 2), 5.1],
        [new Date(2015, 1, 3), 6.2],
        [new Date(2015, 1, 4), 7]
    ];,
    //opt_firstRowIsData: true,
    options: {
        title: 'Shooting history',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        colors: ['#4285F4'],
    },
};
```

Comment: Histogram and Column are different types of charts, although very similar. There are some situations where a column chart will poorly replace a histogram. In my case, for example, I'm using Google Charts' dashboard's controls to make interactive charts. Dinamize a column chart to work as a histogram would be way too much work.