# Google Sheet Histogram Chart x-axis and y-axis have different format

Tags: google-sheets

I have a single column of dates in a google sheet (UK format):

```
Date
----
11/06/2021
18/05/2021
18/05/2021
07/06/2021
07/06/2021
08/06/2021
19/05/2021
19/05/2021
19/05/2021
19/05/2021
19/05/2021
28/05/2021
03/06/2021
17/05/2021
17/05/2021
17/05/2021
25/05/2021
11/05/2021
11/05/2021
```

If I create a Histgram chart, I get this result:
[image: Google Sheets Histgram Chart]

My issue is that the x-axis is showing the date range but formatted as a number and the y-axis is showing the frequency but formatted as a date.

How can I change the format?

This is an example of my problem:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11dHU31RG-ykJrOypMid6Suw8xsvnRD4CByJkM5BUptQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried changing the format of the source data? Menu > Format etc? Make sure its formatted as a date. I just tried it and my axes were fine. Maybe you can share a sheet with test data to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I have added a link to a sheet as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Unfortunately, the only data type that the Histogram supports is plain numbers

Officially its not supported. [Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9146867?hl=en)

Though it seems that its actually picking up the right way to organize it, the formatting of the series is not working.

When I tested it, I just did a bar chart which worked, but for histograms, I got the same result as you.

There is a feature request in the underlying visualization library here:

https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1457

More info here:

- [Create date histogram chart with google histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327803/create-date-histogram-chart-with-google-histogram)